# How do I disable a Config Element in jMeter from the command line

Tags: jmeter

I have a .jmx file that reads data from a CSV and feeds it into a thread loop to run a series of tasks that seed a working data set for tests that'll run later.

During tests, I disabled the CSV and inserted variables to stand for the data that'd come from the CSV. Now I want to have the option to do run the same .jmx from the command-line, but with the CSV Data Set Config element disabled and providing variables equivalent to a single-line CSV, without losing the option of running the same .jmx pointing to a muli-line CSV.

Is there a way to do that or should I use two different .jmx files (generating one from the other is trivial using, say, `sed`)?

Answer (score 0):

1. Instead of having 2 different .jmx files it's more reasonable to have another CSV file with 1 line of variables and parameterise the "Filename" value of the CSV Data Set Config using [__P() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__P) having the default value of the "big" multiline CSV file.
2. JMeter .jmx files are normal XML files so you can change `testname="CSV Data Set Config" enabled="true"` to `testname="CSV Data Set Config" enabled="false"` using whatever approach you like
3. And last but not the least, you can run your JMeter test using [Taurus](https://gettaurus.org/) tool as a wrapper which has [Modifications for Existing Scripts](https://gettaurus.org/docs/JMeter/#Modifications-for-Existing-Scripts) feature so you can disable the CSV Data Set Config as simple as:

   ```
   ---
   execution:
     scenario:
       script: /path/to/your/test.jmx
       modifications:
         disable:
           - CSV Data Set Config
   ```

   More information: [Navigating your First Steps Using Taurus](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/navigating-your-first-steps-using-taurus)

Comment: It would work, but we'd need CSV files for every data items we'd like to use.